# Can't change multi monitor display positions in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 16.04

I've just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and most things are working great :)

However, I have a 3 monitor setup and I'm not able to adjust the relative positions of the displays. If I try and click and drag them they move ever so slightly but just jump back. See screenshot for how they've ended up.

I had an AMD R9 290 is that's of any significance. I'm just using whatever driver came from a fresh install.

Maybe I can set the positions myself in a config file?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE25u.png)

Comment: I have similar issue. I have just updated from 14.04 to 16.04. I used to have my two monitors one on top of the other as they are physically placed. After the update to 16.04 I found them configured side by side. If I try to configure Ubuntu to see them on monitor on top of the other the display goes black and I have to reboot. I have n-Vidia prime driver installed. I tried to update the proprietary nvidia driver from 340 to 364 without any luck.